# Rails 4 getting local variable to js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I've read/researched other answers, but I can't get this to work.  I have a js.erb file that is rendering a partial.  I'm looking to pass a @node variable to it but I get an error in the console `NameError: - undefined local variable or method "node" for #<#<Class:0x007fdcd9163510>:0x007fdcd813b728>`

I'm not sure why it won't grab it.

#### _node.html.erb (node is a local variable in this partial):

```
<div id="tagged_users">
  <%= render partial: "nodes/user_tag_list", locals: { node: node } %>
</div>
```

partial that I would also like rendered in js.erb

#### _user_tag_list.html.erb:

```
<ul>
  <% node.tagged_users.map(&:name).each do |tag| %>
    <li><%= tag %>
      <%= link_to "x", node_path(node, remove_tag: tag), method: :patch %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

#### node#update controller action:

```
def update
  @node = Node.find(params[:id])

  if params.fetch(:node, {}).fetch(:autocomplete_tag_names, false)
    tag = params[:node][:taggable_email]
    @node.user_tag_list.add(tag)
    @node.save

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'user_tag_add.js.erb' }
      end
    elseif
      # ...
    else
    # ...
  end
```

and finally, the js.erb file:

#### user_tag_add.js.erb:

```
$("#tagged_users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'user_tag_list', locals: { node: @node }) %>");
```

A couple of notes.  The logic is sound.  If I replace the html with a string rather than the partial it works fine.  Also, if I `binding.pry` I can set node to @node without issue.  Just can't get the @node to pass to node within the js.erb file.

**EDIT**

Here's the form partial, if useful:

```
<%= form_for node, remote: true, html: { class: "edit_node tag-users" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :autocomplete_tag_names %>
  <%= f.text_field :autocomplete_tag_names, data: { autocomplete_source: users_path }, value: nil %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :taggable_email, value: nil %>
  <%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're using a dated and out-of-favor syntax for rendering partials anyways. Stop using `render partial: x, locals { y: z }` and start simply doing `render x, y: z`. Your example should be written `<%= render "nodes/user_tag_list", node: node %>
`

Comment: Thanks @meager.  Good info.  Would this have solved my problem?  I guess if I included the `nodes/` node it would have.  Appreciate the knowledge drop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ugh, it wasn't the variable scope at all.  In my js.erb file above I originally had:

```
$("#tagged_users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'user_tag_list', locals: { node: @node }) %>");
```

Notice that above I said user_tag_list was a partial?  Well, I didn't specify that in my render statement.  I needed to modify the code to the following:

```
$("#tagged_users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'user_tag_list', locals: {node: @node}) %>");
```

Then it worked.  If anyone else is having issues debugging this type of code to see if it's the variable or not, I went through the following steps creating console messages:

1. Make sure the variable can be seen

   ```
   console.log("<%= @node %>"); response: #&lt;Node:0x007fdcd8203138&gt;
   ```
2. To confirm I wrote a couple of console statements that would extract something out of the object to make sure the correct information was being captured

   ```
   console.log("<%= @node.id %>"); response: 49
   console.log("<%= @node.name %>"); response: 'Test 2'
   ```

Once I saw that the variable was being passed I knew this wasn't the issue, and it looked to make sure I had my `render` statement properly formatted.  Missing `partial` was a big mistake that cost me a few hours of my life.  I hope this post saved got you some time back.

**Additional Info**

One other thing I learned while debugging this:  If you ever want to set a local variable rather than an instance variable (for whatever reason I'm not sure) you can create it in your render statement within your controller action

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'user_tag_add.js.erb', locals: {node: @node} }
end
```

Then you could do something like this within your js.erb file

```
console.log("<%= node %>")
```